# C++ static_cast and dynamic_cast of polymorphic classes using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, casting, unique-ptr

I was practicing static_cast and dynamic_cast on polymorphic classes in C++. I tried it using both raw pointers and unique_ptr. While the former doesn't create problems, the later does. Here I present my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int a, id=0;
    static int i;
public:
    A()
    {
        id=++i;
        cout<<"constructing A: "<<id<<"\n";
    }
    virtual void get()
    {
        cout<<"enter a: ";
        cin>>a;
    }
    virtual void disp()
    {
        cout<<"a = "<<a<<"\n";
    }
    virtual ~A()
    {
        cout<<"destroying A: "<<id<<"\n";
    }
};
int A::i=0;
class B: public A
{
    int b;
public:
    B()
    {
        cout<<"constructing B\n";
    }
    void get()
    {
        cout<<"enter b: ";
        cin>>b;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        cout<<"b = "<<b<<"\n";
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout<<"destroying B\n";
    }
};

void show (unique_ptr<B> &p)
{
    p->get();
    p->disp();
}
void d_cast (unique_ptr<A> &pa)
{
    unique_ptr<B> pb;
    try
    {
        pb.reset(dynamic_cast<B*>(pa.release()));
        if (pb==nullptr)
            throw runtime_error {"nullptr exception"};
        show(pb);
        cout<<"dynamic_cast successful\n\n";
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {
        cout<<"dynamic_cast unsuccessful: "<<e.what()<<"\n\n";
    }
    pa.reset(pb.release());
}
void s_cast (unique_ptr<A> &pa)
{
    unique_ptr<B> pb;
    try
    {
        pb.reset(static_cast<B*>(pa.release()));
        if (pb==nullptr)
            throw runtime_error {"nullptr exception"};
        show(pb);
        cout<<"static_cast successful\n\n";
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {
        cout<<"static_cast unsuccessful: "<<e.what()<<"\n\n";
    }
    pa.reset(pb.release());
}

int main()
{
    cout<<R"(using "unique_ptr<A> pa with new A" :-)"<<"\n\n";
    unique_ptr<A> pa(new A);    // (1)
    d_cast(pa);
    s_cast(pa);      // (2)
    cout<<"\n"<<R"(using "unique_ptr<A> pa with new B" :-)"<<"\n\n";
    pa.reset(new B);
    d_cast(pa);
    s_cast(pa);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is:-

```
using "unique_ptr<A> pa with new A" :-

constructing A: 1
dynamic_cast unsuccessful: nullptr exception

static_cast unsuccessful: nullptr exception


using "unique_ptr<A> pa with new B" :-

constructing A: 2
constructing B
enter b: 7
b = 7
dynamic_cast successful

enter b: 8
b = 8
static_cast successful

destroying B
destroying A: 2
```

I have only 2 questions as I have marked already:-

1. Why isn't the first object {denoted by (1)} destroyed whereas the one called with "new B" is destroyed ?
2. Why is (2) throwing the exception ? Interestingly if i reverse the positioning of `s_cast(pa)` and `d_cast(pa)` then (2) doesn't throw any exception and works fine (problem (1) still persists however).

Comment: pa becomes nullptr after the first d_cast(pa)

Comment: `dynamic_cast<B*>(pa.release())` leaks the object `pa` points to, in case that object is *not* an instance of or derived from `B`: `pa.release` releases the ownership of the unique pointer (which implies it discards the raw pointer stored internally), and `dynamic_cast` discards its argument, if it isn't compatible (returns `nullptr`). So you've lost the address of the object.

Comment: exaclty @dyp thats why i said dat pa becomes nullptr after first d_cast(pa)

Comment: but it should atleast destroy the first object ie (1)

Comment: @AnkitAcharya No, the object (1) is *leaked* as I described in my comment. The object (1) is owned by the `pa` object in `main`, which is the only one who has stored the address of the (1) object. But `pa` releases ownership via `pa.release` in `d_cast`, so the address of (1) is only stored in the return value of `pa.release`. And this return value is the argument of `dynamic_cast`. This argument is *discarded* if the type is incompatible. Now, noone has the address of (1) any more - it has been leaked.

Comment: @dyp Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: @AntonSavin Because I'm *really slow* at writing answers, and I'm really hungry too :) food > rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ! So you need to change your function `d_cast` function definition like this:-

```
void d_cast (unique_ptr<A> &pa)
{
unique_ptr<B> pb;
A *aptr=pa.release();   // make a pointer of type A
try
{
    pb.reset(dynamic_cast<B*>(aptr));   // assign aptr instead of pa.release() here
    if (pb==nullptr)
    throw runtime_error {"nullptr exception"};
    show(pb);
    cout<<"dynamic_cast successful\n\n";
    pa.reset(pb.release());   // reset pa with pb.release() and not with aptr becomes pb has the ownership of aptr
}
catch (exception &e)
{
    cout<<"dynamic_cast unsuccessful: "<<e.what()<<"\n\n";
    pa.reset(aptr);    // reset aptr back to pa as pb holds no ownership of aptr
}
}
```

As you must be knowing the `d_cast` would fail and thus the expression of `dynamic_cast<B*>(pointer_of_type_A)` would return `nullptr`. If there would have been a reference instead of pointer then `std::bad_cast` exception would be thrown. But because you are using the `release()` function, the unique_ptr object `pa` gets rid of the ownership of the pointer and there is no object or pointer to trace it back. Thus you should use `A *aptr` to hold the released pointer and return it to `pa` if the casting fails.

If you do so, your both problems are solved

Comment: the mistake you have made is likely to be made by many programmers